# Facebook.SO Vs regular Stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, site-crossover, mini-site, facebook.stackoverflow

What is the difference between the two sites? Doesn't [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) cover Facebook programming topics? Why is it a separate site instead of just using a [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) tag on the regular [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) site?

Comment: One has really, really sucky questions.  The other, not so much.

Comment: @casper which is which? :D

Comment: I am not able to vote up.How do I gain the reputaion scores to get involved...

Comment: @piyush - you  need to get to 25 rep to vote up, and 125 rep to vote down. See [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/156722) for how to gain reputation.

Comment: @OffBySome Shhh.  We don't want to give away the secret.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Facebook.SO is not a separate site. It's just a **subdomain sponsored by Facebook**. All it does is display questions which are tagged with [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook).

WebApps.SE is a separate site for web applications for *end users*, which would cover most Facebook *end user* questions that are not covered by Stack Overflow's programming question policy.